# Инвертировать порядок строк в файле с помощью Python

Tags: python

Нужно инвертировать порядок строк в текстовом файле. То есть чтобы строки начинались снизу вверх.

Написал код, но работает только с маленькими текстовыми файлами, с большими тоже работает, но очень долго обрабатывает (файл 2мб). Как можно улучшить код, чтобы быстрее работал скрипт?

Пример. В первом файле такой текст:

```
У лукоморья дуб зелёный;
Златая цепь на дубе том:
И днём и ночью кот учёный
Всё ходит по цепи кругом;
```

Результат нужен такой:

```
Всё ходит по цепи кругом;
И днём и ночью кот учёный
Златая цепь на дубе том:
У лукоморья дуб зелёный;
```

Мой код:

```
with open(file1, 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
res = []
for i in lines: res += i
s = ' '
for i in res:
  if i == '\n' : s += '|'
  else: s += i
result = s.split('|')[::-1]
with open(file2, 'w') as f2:
  for i in result:
    print = f2.write(i+"\n")
```

Comment: Про лукоморье - это хорошо. Кстати, кто знает, что такое лукоморье? Это берег моря в форме лука (, излучина берега моря.

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('d.txt','r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    txt=f.readlines()
with open('d1.txt','w', encoding='utf8') as fw:
    fw.write(''.join(txt[::-1]))
```

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Спс поправил, а split, join тормозные?

Comment: `split`, `join` - быстрые. Линейная сложность.

Comment: Удивительно, это работает за 0,15 с, правда, опять с пустой строкой в начале.

Comment: У меня в конце файла строка с `\n` на конце, как и все остальные. Я бы не назвал это лишним.

Comment: До чего приятно с умными людьми пообщаться. Я это про всех тут говорю.

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что приходит на ум

```
with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
  lines = f1.readlines()
with open(file2, 'w') as f2:
  for j in range(len(lines) - 1, -1, -1):
    f2.write(lines[j])
```

@StanislavVolodarskiy:

```
with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
  lines = f1.readlines()
with open(file2, 'w') as f2:
  for line in reversed(lines):
    f2.write(line)
```

~1,5 c оба.

Comment: Нужно сначала создать список, а потом записать его за один раз. А не записывать построчно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy зачем? Просто write(reversed(lines))

Comment: @Эникейщик, `write` не принимает итераторы.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy годится ягодица, время почти такое же.

Comment: @Эникейщик точно, не работает вот это `write(reversed(lines))`.

Comment: @rotabor, цикл без индекса - выше уровень кода - меньше ошибок - легче понять что имелось в виду.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я сомневался на счёт быстродействия, нужно было проверить. Похоже, что `reversed(lines)` тут лениво работает, только итератор реверсом гонит.

Comment: Да, `reversed` - чистый итератор. В точности как вы написали в `range(..., -1, -1)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не помню тонкостей . Тогда lines.reverse(). Хотя для очень большого списка, скорее всего, не очень хорошо так делать с точки зрения памяти. В любом случае, моя мысль была, что надо сначала сделать итоговый список, а потом его сохранить за один раз, а не сохранять каждую строчку отдельно.

Comment: @Эникейщик Oopss это сделал с помощью join.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_table(r'c:\test\textfile_in.txt', sep='\r', header=None)[::-1].to_csv(r'c:\test\textfile_out.txt', header=False, index=False) # можно указать кодировку в аргументе encoding, она по умолчанию 'utf-8' в обоих методах
```

Было (textfile_in.txt)

```
У лукоморья дуб зелёный;
Златая цепь на дубе том:
И днём и ночью кот учёный
Всё ходит по цепи кругом;
```

Стало (textfile_out.txt)

```
Всё ходит по цепи кругом;
И днём и ночью кот учёный
Златая цепь на дубе том:
У лукоморья дуб зелёный;
```